# How do I keep the original order in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code:

```
df <- data.frame(Days = days,Temperature = temp)
pl <- ggplot(df,aes(x=Days,y=Temperature)) + geom_point()
print(pl)
```

When I try running this code it shows the days in alphabetical order instead of the index order (Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri). How can I change it to the correct order?

Comment: @JustinInOz's answer (now deleted) has the right idea (if the wrong solution); `days <- c("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday"); levels(factor(days))` shows you what happens. Try `data.frame(Days=factor(days,levels=unique(days)), Temperature=temp)` [seems only fair to let Justin answer this one if they want ...]

Comment: Set days as a factor and specify the levels in order: `days <- as.factor(days, levels = c("Mon", "Tue",...)` Your example isn't reproducible though, so hard to know exactly your problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below code works:

```
library(ggplot2)

days <- c("Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri")
temp <- c(21, 24, 34, 23, 23)

df2 <- data.frame(Days2=factor(days,levels=unique(days)), Temperature2 = temp)

pl2 <- ggplot(df2,aes(x=Days2,y=Temperature2)) + geom_point()
print(pl2)
```

It produces the below graph: [image]

Comment: The teaching point for both you and the OP is that the ordering of a factor is by its levels attribute. ( don't think Ben Bolker's solution would have been a safe solution because the value for `unique(days)` might or might not have been ordered correctly. Yours is safer.

Comment: how is this answer different from my (admittedly fragile) suggestion in the comments ... ?

Comment: G'Day Ben, it isn't different. It is just a formalisation of your comment in an answer form with toy data set and and output graph. When I put in the toy data, my previous answer did not work. You correction did.

Answer (score 3):

After a little bit of searching I found a built-in English-weekday-abbreviation object (in correct order) by installing the `DescTools` package. Using

```
data.frame(Days=factor(days,levels=DescTools::day.abb), ...)
```

seems to be the most principled way to do this (I can't think of an easy way to do this with weekday name abbreviations from another locale ...)